# Suppressing reduction in fraction box size in multi-level fractions

Tags: formatting

Mathematica display complex fractions like this,

[image]

the second `x` look smaller, I want it look like this, how can I get it in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Use `Text` instead of `TraditionalForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
HoldForm[1/(1 + 1/x)] // TraditionalForm
```

which produces the fraction box in reduced size.

[image: reduced]

Now open the output cell with <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and add `FractionBoxOptions->{AllowScriptLevelChange->False}` at the end.

```
Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
    TagBox[
      FractionBox["1", 
        RowBox[{"1", "+", 
        FractionBox["1", "x"]}]],
      HoldForm], TraditionalForm]], "Output",
  FractionBoxOptions->{AllowScriptLevelChange->False}]
```

Close close the cell with <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and you will see

[image: full-size]

Note. I think on Windows it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

Another way is to use the Option Inspector. Select the output cell and make the following change in the Option Inspector.

[image: option-inspector]

Answer (score 1):

Just an extended comment to the answer of m_goldberg.

Without changing the standard settings in Option Inspector:

```
fractionStyle = Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {FractionBoxOptions -> {AllowScriptLevelChange -> False}}] &;
HoldForm[1/(1 + 1/x)] // fractionStyle // TraditionalForm
```

An additional advantage using DefaultOptions is i.e. having a list of fractions, or any other bigger programming construct, fractionStyle is applied only once at the end (like TraditionalForm).